# Non-linear mixed effect model versus linear mixed model with quadratic terms, which one to choose?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear-model, stata, nonlinear-regression

I am in the process of modeling the predicted immune response since time to last drug dose. Please note that this is illustrative and not really the real context. I have been using `LMM` to model the regression equations

I noticed that, from day 30-60, the slope is (+) which does not really make sense (i.e., it's counterintuitive to say that your immunity increases the longer you have been given the drug, while in reality one would expect your immunity to drop over time. On the other hand, from day 60 onwards, the slope gets (-). I tried adjusting for potential confounders etc., but it didn't solve the problem.

I then came across non-linear mixed effect (`NLME`) and thought that it might be a better fit. Simple twoway observation of the data reveals that the pattern of the data follows a quadratic formula: `y = c + x + x^2`.

Seeing this, I am confused on whether it is better to use NLME or LMM with quadratic terms (i.e., interacting variable `x` with `x` so that it becomes `x^2`). So in stata the code will be like this: `mixed y x##x || random:`.

What's the difference? Which one should I use and what are the statistical considerations?

#p.s.: I am using Stata, am very new to NLME and am having difficulties in building the NLME models.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-linear mixed effects models can model very complex relationships and can be particularly useful when you can specify some biologically plausible model (where there may be random effects for subjects on multiple model parameters). E.g. one example is modeling dose response in clinical trials, where maybe you speculate that the treatment effect follows an Emax relationship such as $\Delta_\text{to placebo} = \text{E}_\max \times \text{dose}/(\text{dose} + \text{ED}_{50})$ and you think the $\text{E}_\max$ and $\text{ED}_{50}$ parameters vary across patients. Or, one might describe drug absorption, distribution in the body, elimination from the body binding to a target receptor and resulting efficacy via some linked differently equations with some of the rates of things happening having random subject effects. Such biologically motivated models can work very well for extrapolating beyond their training data, if they capture core aspects of the true data generating mechanism very well. On the other hand, such models can be hard to build/fit, especially if your data do not actually inform the parameters (or the extent of between-subject variability) very well (ideally, one would design the experiment under analysis up-front to be as informative for the intended model as possible).

In contrast, models with polynomial (e.g. quadratic) terms (which are of course in a sense simple non-linear mixed models) tend to be primarily for interpolating/describing the training data and often extrapolate very badly beyond the training data (with large enough numbers the quadratic term will dominate and extrapolate a quadratic relationship, while on the training data things were "carefully calibrated" to make sense/be counterbalanced by the linear term). Certain splines (e.g. cubic with linear trends only beyond the outer knots) tend to do this a little better, but there's still no reason they would necessarily extrapolate well.

What both have in common is some random effects for subject on some model terms that induce correlation between observations of the same subject, which there should be.

Comment: Hi @Bjorn thank you very much for your responses! In that case I believe NLMEM is the appropriate model for my analysis. Do you have any good, practical references on NLMEM model building with Stata? I am having difficulties in finding one because the Stata tutorials are very context-specific, so it's quite hard to extrapolate the tutorial to another type of dataset. Thanks!

Comment: Not a Stata user, I'd normally use something like brms in R (or more in the past NLMIXED in SAS).

Comment: Thanks! @Björn Sorry I had one more question I just remembered regarding this topic: I initially modeled the LMM splines using time periods so there are 2 splines for each model (e.g. day 30-60 and day 90-180). I noticed that LMM with quadratic terms provide similar results to this, is there any consideration on which to use? Or are they the same?

Thanks!